# Pandas: after dropping value is still present

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I tried to drop value and plot the countplot but values are still there. What am I doing wrong?

```
df = df.drop(df[(df['market_segment'] == 'Undefined') & (df['market_segment'] == 'Aviation')].index)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.countplot(x='market_segment',data=df,hue='hotel')
plt.show()
```

[image: The chart I'm getting]

Comment: how can rows in the "Market Segment" column have two different values at the same time?

Comment: @PaulH I'm trying to drop both 'Undefined' and 'Aviation' from market_segment

Comment: You need an `or` (`|`) instead of an `and` (`&`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 reasons this may be happening.

1. Your first line where you are filtering is incorrect
2. Your "market_segment" column may be a categorical dtype. In a categorical dtype Series, values that are not observed in the data can be propagated into `seaborn`, so converting to an object or string dtype can remedy this issue.

```py
df = (
  df.loc[~df["market_segment"].isin(["Undefined", "Aviation"])]
  .astype({"market_segment": str})
)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.countplot(x='market_segment',data=df,hue='hotel')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're removing rows where `market_segment` is both `Undefined` *and* `Aviation`. That, obviously, is nonsense logic.

Change your AND (`&`) to OR (`|`):

```py
df = df.drop(df[(df['market_segment'] == 'Undefined') | (df['market_segment'] == 'Aviation')].index)
#                                                     ^ changed from & to |
```

That way, all rows will be dropped where `market_segment` is either `Undefined` or `Aviation`. If it's one of those, it will be remove.